# How to make an algorithm for select all options?

Tags: swift

I want make a good algorithm for select all options, and I came with this code:

```
var option1: Bool = false
var option2: Bool = false
var option3: Bool = false
var option4: Bool = false
var option5: Bool = false
var selectAll: Bool {
    get {
        return option1 && option2 && option3 && option4 && option5
    }
    set(newValue) {
        if newValue {
            option1 = true
            option2 = true
            option3 = true
            option4 = true
            option5 = true
        }
        else {
            option1 = false
            option2 = false
            option3 = false
            option4 = false
            option5 = false
        }
    }
}
```

This code try to respect each options be true or false, but if we set select all to true, I want all options be true and if I set select all to false, I want all options be false. I have a feeling that I could improve this code or changing the codes to better algorithm, in real project this options are 10. Is there any known algorithm for this kind of works? or this the best i could get?

Comment: Things can be made easier if you have one property that is an array of Bool. It makes the code easier for what you've shown but it makes it harder to access the correct index when you want to use a single option. Another approach is an "OptionSet" struct with a constant for each option and then only one property is needed. See [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) for an example.

Comment: Well you don't need the if/else in the set, `option1 = newValue option2 = newValue ...` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a whole bunch of variables of the same type and you want to manipulate them all at once, an array is the way to go.

Say you set up an array of 10 options:

```
var options = [Bool](repeating: true, count: 10)
```

The if you say `print("after creating, options = \(options)")`
you'll get:

> after creating, options = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]

Now let's say you define a function `setOptions(to:)`. That might look like this:

```
func newValue: Bool) {
    for index in options.startIndex..<options.endIndex  {
        options[index] = newValue
    }
}
```

And say you call it like this:

```
setOptions(to: false)
print("after 'setOptions(to: false)', options = \(options)")
```

That would output:

> after 'setOptions(to: false)', options = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]

That function operates on a global variable `options`. Global variables have some problems. Another way to write the function would be to have it take an `inout` var parameter (a parameter that can be modified in place.

The new function might look like this:

```
func setArray(_ array: inout [Bool], toValue value: Bool) {
    for index in array.startIndex..<array.endIndex  {
        array[index] = value
    }
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
setArray(&options, toValue: true)
print("after 'setArray(&options, toValue: true)', options = \(options)")
```

And it would output the following:

> after 'setArray(&options, toValue: true)', options = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]

### Edit:

As HangarRash points out in their comment, if all you want to do is set every option in your array to the same value, it would be simpler, cleaner, and faster to just say

```
options = [Bool](repeating: true, count: 10)
```

I explained how to iterate through the array assuming that at some point you'd need to do more complex things to each element.

For example, say you want to be able to interrogate array elements based on their **meaning** rather than their value.

You could creat an enum that let you index into the array:

```
enum OptionsIndex: Int {
    case isLarge
    case isBald
    case isDry
    case isSmelly
    case isOrange
    case isFlat
    case isExpensive
    case isFun
    case isALie
    case isAttractive
}
```

And then you could use code like this:

```
print("options[isOrange] = \(options[OptionsIndex.isOrange.rawValue])")
```

With a little more work, you could make that even more elegant and skip the ugly `typename.valueName.rawVaue` nonsense.

Comment: Why not reinitialize the array with `repeating…` instead of using a loop to set all values to the same value?

Comment: Sure. If you really want to force the array to always the same value, using repeating would be better. But if you later want to do more complex things with the whole array, knowing how to index into it is probably more helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice, actually I am using an array of options in my real project and also I am using a For-Loop for set all true or false like you answered, since this select all is itself is an option we agree about setValue part with your answer, what is your answer for get part? because when I am going show the value of select all in UIKit, Cocoa or SwiftUI, ... I have to get the value of select all to translate the true or false value as user interface, I am able to work around about the interface but I am interested to getting and reading value for select all option, any idea?

Comment: `options.allSatisfy {$0}`